# Hudson/Jenkins $WORKSPACE variable not working on node

Tags: hudson, jenkins, environment-variables, workspace, slave

So I have a `version.txt` file in my Source Control.  I check it out on master and build, and have the Set Environment Variables through a file with the File Path being
`$WORKSPACE/Version.txt`

On the master it correctly finds the Version.txt and sets `MAJOR=x` etc..

When I do the same build on a slave node, with the same configuration I always get a

```
[envfile] Reading environment variables from file.
[envfile] Path to file: /var/hudson/workspace/DEV_BUILD/Version.txt
[envfile] Can not find environment file. Path to file=[/var/hudson/workspace/DEV_BUILD/Version.txt]
```

but I see earlier that:

```
Building remotely on cent5.5_64
Cleaning the workspace because project is configured to clean the workspace before each build.
server: 192.168.1.207
[UGCS_DEV_BUILD] $ sscm get / -wreplace  -d/var/hudson/workspace/DEV_BUILD -r
```

get from main/DEV:

```
/var/hudson/workspace/DEV_BUILD/Version.txt
```

I am guessing `$WORKSPACE` refers to the master?  Anyone have any ideas how to get this to work on a Slave?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the EnvFile plugin isn't working with slaves :
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-9546

Moreover from the comments in this JIRA, they suggest to use the `EnvInject` plugin : https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin

Regards,